# How to fire an event after a multi-dimensional for loop with $.get() requests?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays chosen1 & chosen2. The items in these arrays are my $.get() properties that I send. I am trying to render a Highcharts chart (called using the renderChart()) function once the loop is complete. I tried multiple solutions and ended up with the code below. How do I listen for when all the $.get() requests are done so I can fire the Highcharts function on the page?

```
var chosen1         = [],
    chosen2         = [],
    computedSeries  = [],
    XHRs            = [];

function getData() {
    var rebuildingChart = '<div id="rebuilding-chart"><div id="floatingCirclesG"><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07"></div><div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08"></div></div><p>Crunching Data</p></div>';

    $('#cc-chart').children().remove();
    $('#cc-chart').html(rebuildingChart);

    $(chosen1).each(function() {
        var fruits = this;
        $(chosen2).each(function() {
            var veggies = this;
            XHRs.push($.get("/fetchData", {fruit: fruits, veggie: veggies}, function(data) {
                var chartJSON       = data,
                    selectedKPI     = veggies,
                    singleSeries    = {},
                    KPIData         = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < chartJSON.length; i++) {
                    var point = [];
                    point.push(chartJSON[i]['utc_time']);
                    point.push(Math.round(chartJSON[i]['kpi_value']));
                    KPIData.push(point);
                };

                singleSeries["name"] = selectedKPI;
                singleSeries["data"] = KPIData;
                computedSeries.push(singleSeries);
            }));
        });
    });

    $.when(XHRs).then(function() {
        renderChart();
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `$.when.apply($, XHRs).then(f)`?

Comment: Consider [jQuery Promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: @elclanrs That totally worked! Thank you! I can mark  your solution as an answer if you add it instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`$.when` takes deferreds as arguments, if you want to pass an array, you need to call the function using `apply`:

```
$.when.apply($, XHRs).then(...)
```